# Problem posting to the user's wall using Graph Api

Tags: javascript, facebook, sdk

I am trying to post to the wall. It does not work when i add arguments like link, name and caption.

```
function graphStreamPublish(){
                var body = 'This is a test feed';
                var url = 'http://www.my-site.com';
                var heading = 'Check out the link.';
                var caption = 'I am trying to get it work.';  
                FB.api('/me/feed', 'post', { message: body, link: link, name: heading, caption: caption}, function(response) {
                    if (!response || response.error) {
                        alert('Error occured');
                    } else {
                        alert('Post ID: ' + response.id);
                    }
                });
            }
```

I understand the link, name and caption are cceptable parameters. Am i missing something. It works fine with just message argument.

I appreciate all your help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

First of all your link variable name is `url` and you are sending `link`.

I think I know what's the problem. Facebook doesn't like posting a link without a description (undocumented feature?). I faced similar problem, when I added description to the message it went through.